# What does я нажигаю через водный mean?

Tags: перевод

I can't find any good translations of the following sentence. Please, help me.

Comment: In what context did you find this phrase? It is meaningless without a context.

Comment: the phrase does not make sense in a normal speech

Comment: Dmitry, It is a drug-slang phrase that has a meaning even without a context. As for "normal speech", this phrase wouldn't make sense for if any drug-slang

Comment: This phrase makes sense and even without any context. It's just pure drug-slang. The words themselves here create the context.

Answer (score 12):

A slang. *Водный* [vˈodnᵻj] (also: *водник, водяной, мокрый*, in a broader sense: *бульбулятор, булик, бульб, буль*) is homemade smoking device. Usually refers to smoking marijuana. I do not know how it is properly called in English and attach a photos.

[image]
[image]
[image]

"я нажигаю через водный" = I smoke through the '*Водный*'

Comment: Great pictures! There is also a joke that night kiosks should bundle Coca-Cola bottles with chocolate and chopsticks. These are the main components for this device (chocolate is needed for the aluminium foil it's wrapped in and chopsticks are used to perforate the foil).

Answer (score 3):

Highly slangy; new to me too. Apparently it refers to smoking a bong.